Map-matching on table of geometries
I have a table that represents an OSM map. Each row representes an edge of the graph. It has the following attributes:

road_id,
start_node,
end_node,
direction,
linestring

I want to mapmatch a trace of GPS points using this data.
How can I do it?
Regarding the map, it's an old map and that's the only data I have of it. I have to use it because I need the ID of the road to reference some other data.
